# What are causes of "Largest Contentful Paint element Error!" in PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I am experiencing an error in PSI where the largest contentful paint has an error across several pages of a site. The images are small in size (~22kb) and no apparent changes have been made to the page but we recently experienced an increase in LCP issues but are unable to determine the cause due to this error.

I tried running the PSI test in multiple browsers and in incognito modes to see if I got a different result but to no avail. I expected to see recommendations for fixing the long LCP issue but there are none.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the latest version of Lighthouse when using PageSpeed Insights. It's even happening on Google's own site (web.dev). I've opened a bug report. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/15075